# Selenium webdriver for Chrome does not to send the char(94) or "^" sign

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I'm trying to fill out a form using Selenium in Python 3.7. Login works fine, but password includes "^" sign (ASCII 94). And Selenium seems not to process/send this sign.

I have already tried working around this using ActionChains and  pressing shift+6 using that as well as pressing ALT+NUM9+NUM4. None of these seem to work even though i can easily login manually.

```py
username = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
username.send_keys("my@email.com")
passw = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
passw.send_keys("my_password_includes^_sign")
```

I expect the exact strings to come up in forms but instead in password something along the lines of my_password_includes_sign comes up. (i tried sending it to login form so that it's visible)

Comment: Did you try sending keyword through JavaScript Executor ?

Comment: I would like to avoid using JavaScript Executors if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Selenium can't type some special characters, in this occasions, send the unicode instead ([^ unicode is U+005E, and it's escape sequence is \u005E](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html)):

```
passw.send_keys("my_password_includes\u005E_sign")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `Alt` + `94` part, try

```
passw.send_keys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, "9"), Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, "4"))
```